# PHP Unit Testing - Test a feature with a service instance inside it

Tags: php, phpunit

I am learning the art of testing and need some of your help. I have a feature (legacy code) that I need to test, this feature receives some data as parameters, save it temporally in the database and sends to an external API. If the api response is 200 then updates the data in the table to persist it definitely, otherwise it deletes it.

This is the code:

```
public function sendAssignments(Challenge $challenge, int $reportType)
{
    $reportModel      = new Report($challenge, $reportType);
    $pointsList       = $this->calculateAssignments($challenge, $reportType);
    $pharmsToSend     = $pointsList['pharmsCollection'];
    $pointsArray      = $pointsList['pointsArray'];

    $savedAt          = Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $symfonyService   = new SymfonyService();
    $requestUid       = \uniqid('AS-', false);

    $sentAt           = Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $reportModel->persistReportAssignments($pharmsToSend, $savedAt, $sentAt, false);
    $symfonyResult    = $symfonyService->sendReportPoints(
        $requestUid, 
        $challenge->challenge_id, 
        $pointsArray
    );

    if ($symfonyResult->code == "200") {
        // Actualizamos los datos
        $reportModel->persistReportAssignments($pharmsToSend, $savedAt, $sentAt, true);
        FlashMessage::addSuccess('Se han asignado los puntos del reporte.', 'Asignación correcta');
    } else {
        $reportModel->deleteFailedAssignmentsFromDatabase($savedAt);
        FlashMessage::addError($symfonyResult->msg, 'Error '.$symfonyResult->code.' - No se han asignado los puntos');
    }

    if ($reportType == Report::REPORT_CONNECTED) {
        return redirect()->route('reports.showConnectedReport', ['challenge'=>$challenge]);
    } else if ($reportType == Report::REPORT_MANUAL) {
        return redirect()->route('reports.showManualReport', ['challenge'=>$challenge]);
    }
}
```

I am testing the feature, not the API call, so I wanna mock the SymfonyService class, for this I has written a new class:

```
class SymfonyServiceMock
{
    public function sendReportPoints()
    {
        return ["operation"=>"ok", "code" => 200];
    }
}
```

But the problem is that SymfonyService is being instantiated inside the feature, so I cannot use the SymfonyServiceMock class to simulate the API call. And here is my doubt, may I have to refactor the feature in order to pass the SymfonyService to it? Is this the correct approach?

I mean some refactor like this one:

```
public function sendAssignments(Challenge $challenge, int $reportType, SymfonyService $symfonyService)
{
    // The rest of the code here, but without instantiating SymfonyService
}
```

If you have another better idea about how it would be the best way to test it (following SOLID principles of course) I would be glad to know.

Thanks a lot in advance

**EDIT:**
I had this idea, I have registered the SymfonyService on the AppServiceContainer, and now I inject the SymfonyService on the controller so I can refactor like this:

```
public function sendAssignments(Challenge $challenge, int $reportType)
{
    $this->executeSendAssignmentsOperation($challenge, $reportType);

    if ($reportType == Report::REPORT_CONNECTED) {
        return redirect()->route('reports.showConnectedReport', ['challenge'=>$challenge]);
    } else if ($reportType == Report::REPORT_MANUAL) {
        return redirect()->route('reports.showManualReport', ['challenge'=>$challenge]);
    }
}

public function executeSendAssignmentsOperation(Challenge $challenge, int $reportType)
{
    $reportModel      = new Report($challenge, $reportType);
    $pointsList       = $this->calculateAssignments($challenge, $reportType);
    $pharmsToSend     = $pointsList['pharmsCollection'];
    $pointsArray      = $pointsList['pointsArray'];

    $savedAt          = Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sentAt           = Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $reportModel->persistReportAssignments($pharmsToSend, $savedAt, $sentAt, false);
    $symfonyResult    = $this->_symfonyService->sendReportPoints(
        $challenge, 
        $pointsArray,
        $reportType
    );

    $sentAt           = Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if ($symfonyResult->code == "200") {
        // Actualizamos los datos
        $reportModel->persistReportAssignments($pharmsToSend, $savedAt, $sentAt, true);
        FlashMessage::addSuccess('Se han asignado los puntos del reporte.', 'Asignación correcta');
    } else {
        $reportModel->deleteFailedAssignmentsFromDatabase($savedAt);
        FlashMessage::addError($symfonyResult->msg, 'Error '.$symfonyResult->code.' - No se han asignado los puntos');
    }
}
```

With this refactor now I can write the test. But, I am still wondering if this is the correct approach for the problem. If not, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem with PhpUnit. It is impossible to mock class created within the System Under Test.

The only solution which worked for me was to test the code using Kahlan (https://github.com/kahlan/kahlan) which allows to mock the classes on the fly. But it requires the classes to be autoloader via composer.

Maybe this will help a little :)

Comment: Well, I managed mocking by my hand, I mean I dont know how mock classes on the fly, but I did inherited the service and overrided the method to return always true.  Injecting in Laravel container makes me possible to pass the mocked object. What I need is an explanation if there is a better approach, and how.

Comment: Yeap DI is great but you had to amend the System Under Test to make it testable :) Kahlan allows to test without modification of the source code

Comment: It amends your code on the fly via its own autoloader